# Where is the rc file for vi editor

Tags: vi

I would like to set up system-wide `vi` settings.

I know i can setup preferences for `vim` editor in `/etc/vimrc` and `~/.vimrc`

but I don't think my `vi` on CentOS7 is reading anything from the vimrc files or locations such as `/etc/virc` or `~/.virc`

Comment: Try `find /etc -name vimrc`

Comment: While this is for Ubuntu (Debian) rather than CentOS (RedHat) http://askubuntu.com/questions/60041/why-isnt-vim-reading-my-global-configuration-file - the information may be useful.

Comment: You can use any file you want that you `source` in `$EXINIT`. `~/.exrc` and `$EXINIT` are always ignored when calling `vi/ex/open` on a file named `-` though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Poking at [POSIX](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/vi.1posix):

```
Initialization in ex and vi
   See  Initialization  in  ex  and  vi  for  a  description  of ex and vi
   initialization for the vi utility.
```

And the [manpage for `ex`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ex.1posix) says:

```
   IEEE Std 1003.1-2001  does  not  mention system-wide ex and vi start-up
   files. While they exist in several implementations of ex and  vi,  they
   are  not  present in any implementations considered historical practice
   by IEEE Std 1003.1-2001.  Implementations that have such  files  should
   use  them  only if they are owned by the real user ID or an appropriate
   user (for example, root on UNIX systems) and if they are  not  writable
   by  any  user other than their owner. System-wide start-up files should
   be read before the EXINIT variable, $HOME/.exrc, or local  .exrc  files
   are evaluated.
```

So I suppose `/etc/exrc` is your best bet for old-school `vi`.

However, `vi` on CentOS 7 is likely just `vim-minimal`, in which case the startup files will still be using `vim` in their name: `/etc/vimrc` or `/etc/vim/vimrc`.

Answer (score 3):

The question is specifically about CentOS7, and mentions vim.  That can only be one of a few packages: `vim-minimal`, `vim-enhanced`, `vim-x11`.  CentOS does not provide packages for other implementations of vi, such as `nvi`.

The package description for `vim-minimal` says

> The vim-minimal package includes a minimal version of
>   VIM, which is installed into /bin/vi for use when only the root
>   partition is present.

and `man vi` gives the vim manpage, which lists the system configuration files used:

```
   /etc/vimrc     System wide Vim initializations.
   /etc/gvimrc    System wide gvim initializations.
```

and since there is no mention of `gvim`, the proper answer is `/etc/vimrc`.

Note that vim's documentation does **not** list a different configuration file when running as `vi`.  There are no `/etc/virc` or `~/.virc` files.

Actually, POSIX avoids telling where *any* system configuration files might reside.  Keith Bostic (who wrote most of the [POSIX description of vi](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/vi.html)) used a different system configuration file for `nvi`:

```
   /etc/vi.exrc
```

Besides not mentioning system configuration files, Bostic also chose not to document *modelines* (or implement them in `nvi`).  The two are related.  Other implementations of `vi` provide (optionally or not) a way to read a configuration file from the current directory.  That can lead to unexpected results, and modelines can aggravate that.  The Unix systems (AIX, HPUX, Solaris) make these features optional (as do `elvis`, and `vim`), based on the settings `exrc` and `modeline`. `nvi` also uses the `exrc` setting for the same purpose.

vim's manpage does not mention, but the help/documentation does say that if it cannot find a suitable `~/.vimrc`, it will look for `/.exrc` (no `/etc/exrc`).  The `~/.exrc` was documented for [SunOS 4](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=vi&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=SunOS%204.1.3&arch=default&format=html).  [Solaris 10](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=vi&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=SunOS%205.10&arch=default&format=html) likewise mentions `~/.exrc`, but not `/etc/exrc`.

Further reading:

- [vim initialization](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#initialization) (describes configuration files)
- [vim modelines](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#modeline) are enabled by default; Unix and elvis disable them by default.

Comment: Superb answer!!